# ENTRYPOINT & CMD commands with mongod results in unknown option error

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am using multiple Dockerfiles to setup my server infrastructure. One of the Dockerfiles I build is a MongoDB server which will be linked to a running web server application in a later step. Currently, I have the problem when running the MongoDB server I receive following error:

```
"Error parsing command line: unknown option port 27017"
```

In my Dockerfile I have:

```
CMD ["--port 27017", "--dbpath /data/db", "--smallfiles"]    
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/mongod"]
```

When I use instead of the above commands the following everything works:

```
CMD /usr/bin/mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db --smallfiles
```

I prefer the CMD - Array and ENTRYPOINT approach more but cannot figure out why I receive the error.

Comment: first thing to try would be to take out the port and dbpath parameters, after all that is what you get as defaults anyway.  What happens if you make it just `CMD ["--smallfiles"]`?

Comment: This question is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390620/entrypoint-cmd-commands-with-mongod-results-in-unknown-option-error and has been answered on SO.

Comment: The Question was answered at: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390620/entrypoint-cmd-commands-with-mongod-results-in-unknown-option-error

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate out the arguments in the array like:

```
CMD ["--port", "27017", "--dbpath", "/data/db", "--smallfiles"]    
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/mongod"]
```

See this duplicate answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24392379/684908